# How to use `for` with filereader?

Tags: java, for-loop, compiler-errors, syntax-error, filereader

If I want to read 20 lines in Text file with File Reader and I don't want repeat 20 lines or `string str4=br4.readLine` line I want to use for with `for` like this:

```
FileReader fr4 = new FileReader("HardDisk.txt");
BufferedReader br4=new BufferedReader(fr4);
for(int i =0; i<=20; i++)
String str4=br4.readLine();
 br4.close();
```

but it doesn't work for me it shows an error:

> Variable declaration not allowed here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to distinguish the keyword. I've fixed some typo and grammar. I've properly quoted the error message. I also aligned your code sample so that it renders properly - please see [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting. Finally, I specified the programming tag (Java) so more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please make sure your first sentence is clear. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare a variable in a one-liner block. Just surround it with curly braces and you should be OK:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    String str4 = br4.readLine();
}
```

Comment: also, unless this is just example code, str4 is only going to have the value that is set on the last pass. Not sure of the input so can't say, but perhaps += is in order.